# Is it correct to propagate multiple events at once using RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, amqp

I am developing an application using microservice architecture.
Imagine there are 3 microservices.

- Users-Microservice(Stores user information (Username, Password Etc...))
- Mailing-Microservice (Responsible for sending mail)
- UserInfo-Microservice (Stores user information (Name, Surname Etc...))

UserInfo and Mailing microservices are listening to Users microservice.

when a user is created

- UserInfo microservice wants to get this information(Name,Surname etc...)
- Mailing microservice wants to get this information(E-mail address)

**Question**

- Do I have to create an event (UserCreatedEvent) and send all the information?
  (Name,Surname,E-mail address)

  **Problem**

  UserInfo microservice does not need E-mail address information

  Mailing microservice does not need Name,Surname information
- Is it a correct usage to publish two different?

  _publishEndPoint.publish(UserInfoData);

  _publishEndPoint.publish(MailData);

Answer (score 3):

In broad strokes, there are two approaches to coordinating multiple services, Orchestration and Choreography:

- Service Orchestration refers to an *imperative* coordination style, here imperative coordination referring to a *sequence* of instructions  with explicit control and data flow.
- Service Choreography refers to a *declarative* coordination style, here declarative coordination referring to a *set* of instructions with implicit control and data flow.

**Service Orchestration**

In Service Orchestration there is a dedicated orchestrator, for example a Saga or a Workflow. The orchestrator calls your services in the desired sequence for example User Service, User Info Service, Mailing Service.

Here, the orchestrator has a direct dependency on the 3 services, however, the services do not have any dependencies.

[image: Service Orchestration]

**Service Choreography**

In Service Choreography, there is no dedicated orchestrator. Services publish events and react to events for example the User Service publishes the UserCreatedEvent, the User Info and Mailing Service react to the UserCreatedEvent.

Here, the User Service, the User Info Service, and the Mailing Service have a direct dependency on the UserCreatedEvent

[image: Service Choreography]

Generally, emitting different projections of the same event e.g. UserInfoData and MailData, both projections of the UserCreatedEvent is not common and does not simplify your dependency relationship

[image: Service Choreography, 2 events instead of 1 event]

**Conclusion**

According to your description, you are opting for Service Choreography. The reality of Choreography is a complex event/service dependency relationship that signifies control and data flow - if you want to change control flow or data flow chances are high you have to alter multiple services accordingly.

You may want to consider Service Orchestration as well and implement the [saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) or implement a workflow via a tool like [temporal.io](https://temporal.io)

(*Disclaimer* I work at [temporal.io](https://temporal.io))

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am also happy for the effort you put into the images. Thanks to you, I solved my problem. :)